# What is the concept behind silicon magnetics in the episode Such Great Patience?

Tags: seaquest

How was the (non-holographic) holographic alien supposed to be able to move through solid material? They mentioned a theory with "silicon magnetics" but it went over my head.

[image: Silicon Alien - Seaquest]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script was pretty clear on the order of events;

1) There's silicon dust in the air
2) The aliens can manipulate silicon using their science
3) The alien we see isn't a hologram but rather a visual illusion caused by manipulating the silicon in the air

> Interior Launch: by hole in alien ship
>
> **Manilow Crocker:** *Almost got it.  We’re all through, Commander.*
>
> **Scott Keller:** *Take an atmosphere reading.  **Heavy silicon compounds**, large    concentrations of xenon and argon.*
>
> **Tim O’Neill:** *Traces of carbon, helium; parts per million asbestos.*
>
> **Scott Keller:** *Not breathable, but it’s not gonna corrode our suits either.*

and then a few minutes later;

> **Professor Martinson:** *I would say more a hologram, a projection, like myself.  I call attention to your earlier encounter with the
>   alien.  Notice the sand residue when it passes through the bulkhead.*
>
> **Kristin Westphalen:** *Could this be silicon magnetics?*
>
> **Professor Martinson:** *Unproven, though that would be an answer.*
>
> **Kristin Westphalen:** *Such as our magnets attract iron, their’s could attract free floating molecules of silicon which pull together
>   into the shape we see.*
>
> **Nathan Bridger:** *So while his magnetic field can go through that wall, the material he attracts can’t.*